# Best way to unit test an API call that hits the application when running

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

Right now we are working on building a custom CMS but I am running into a roadblock where I can't quite figure out the best approach with a piece of it to allow for good unit testing.

Our process is as follows:

The request comes in --> Parse the page for components --> Found component --> Hit the component API to get the component content

The only issue is when unit testing we hit the local URL for the app, which won't work since the app isn't fully running when running tests.

Component Rendering Code:

```
var componentBody = await httpClient
            .GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/Api/Components/" + ComponentName + "/View/" + ComponentId);
ComponentStructure componentStructure = this.ParseHtml(componentBody);
```

Unit Testing Code:

```
public async Task TestPageParsing()
    {
        this.pagesClient = this.clientManager.GetClient<Page, PageData>("pages");
        var pages = await this.pagesClient.GetAsync();
        this.pageParsingService.FindComponents(pages.Items[0].Data.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to test the behavior and not the underlying platform, a unit test is all you need. You do this by mocking out your platform dependencies (database, http, et cetera) and replacing them with mocks that return hard coded facts. Leave the platform specifics to manual testing. If you really want to write an integration test, it should still be automated in your test framework; not requiring manual setup for a developer to run the test. Categorize these separately though so people can run your fast unit tests separately from the slow and long running integration tests.

It sounds like behavior is what you want. For instance, your http web api returns back a blob of html that you want to parse. You don't even need a mock in this case, if you're just trying to test that `ParseHtml` works.

```
var html = "<html />";

var result = myObj.ParseHtml(html);

// Make some assertion here
```

You can write multiple test cases based on expected html, and you can also add test cases for potential malformatted html, or other unexpected scenarios to ensure `ParseHtml` behaves as expected.

Comment: For some reason this clarified a lot for me. I think I was taking too broad of an approach with things here and I really need to be testing things on a more detailed scale like you are talking about with ParseHTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an integration test instead of a unit test.

You could mock out the call to the application and present the calling function with a fixed response instead, and verify that it renders correctly.